# How to use CoreData effectively in fetching many Managed Objects in the background and updating UI on the main thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, core-data

I am trying to fetch thousands of NSManageObjects in the background and update UI using those objects on the main thread. In the Apple document, It is written that the developer should pass the objectId of NSManagedObject when use the same objects between the threads. But, I think it is inefficient to fetch again by objectId on the main thread.

One way to avoid it is to create the subclass of NSObject to hold the attributes of NSManagedObject which to be needed to update UI and set it to the array, and use that array on the main thread.

Is there any good idea?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of good ideas, starting with the suggestions from Apple.  In addition, SO is full of posts about performing background fetch and update.  You should do some research, and then come back here with specific, well thought out questions.  You will then receive all the help you need.

Comment: When Apple recommends fetching again by objectID, they are not saying that just to create more work for you. If you share NSManagedObjects across threads, your app WILL crash. Read up on `-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:]` to make sure you are ALWAYS accessing the managed objects on the correct thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a question that has been answered on this site so many times.

The easiest solution for you is to work with a background context to insert and update your new data and rely on the practical `NSFetchedResultsController`, using a main thread context, to update your UI.

Comment: If the question has been answered so many times then you could simply close it as a duplicate :)

Comment: I don't really get it why it is needed to insert or update in the background. I just want to use fetched managed objects by the background managedObjectContext even on the main thread.

Comment: @MartinR Any suggestions for the appropriate SOF question? Perhaps merrill should do the research ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Of course I have already read the Apple documents, and I have already known about what you are suggesting. But, after all it seems I have not any other choice other than objectID.  Fetching with an objectID is more faster than fetching at the first time, and I am doing so on the main thread.

Comment: You should not fetch data from the web on the main thread. You can do all of this mostly without objectIDs. If you mean a long fetch from the database (100.000 plus records), you can do that in the background as well.